removing ghost js-asset in odoo 16
After having removed a js asset file (kanban_controller_zsb.js) from one of my custom module (event_xsb1) in odoo 16, it is still remaining and causes trouble to load new js assets of other custom modules to customize a kanban-view.
In the Browser console, this error is displayed:
Missing dependencies:     
Array [ "web.Sidebar" ]
web.assets_common.min.js:formatted:299:16
Non loaded modules:       
Array [ "event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb" ]
​
0: "event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb"
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []
web.assets_common.min.js:formatted:321:14
Debug:                    
Object { "event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb": {…} }
​
"event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb": Object { dependencies: (3) […], dependents: [], name: "event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb", … }
​​
dependencies: Array(3) [ "web.core", "web.KanbanController", "web.Sidebar" ]
​​​
0: "web.core"
​​​
1: "web.KanbanController"
​​​
2: "web.Sidebar"
​​​
length: 3
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
dependents: Array []
​​
missing: Array [ "web.Sidebar" ]
​​
name: "event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb"




I have already tried to Regenerate the assets bundles, but it does not help.

I have already tried to find this asset manually (in App-Settings > Assets) but i could not find it.

I can not find this asset in the Database table neither:


SELECT * FROM public.ir_asset
 WHERE path LIKE '%kanban_controller_zsb%'


I have tried to find if the assets.xml of this module in the previous odoo version (v13) remains in my current version (v16) but i could not find this file or its content in any views of my current odoo v16.

In Odoo 13, the involved module: event_xsb1 had this content:

Now in Odoo 16, the involved module: event_xsb1 has this content:

So that i am really wondering where this js script is located.
Any idea how to remove it properly ?

It could be that the asset is still referenced somewhere in your manifest file, or a browser/server cache issue ?

The reason was that the odoo.define('event_xsb1.kanban_controller_zsb') at the top of the js file was related to the module of its previous location: 'event_xsb1' instead of the name of the new module where it was moved to...
